# Hikvision plug-in not detected

Tags: firefox, plugins, camera, stream

I have a Hikvision thermal camera and I do not receive any live stream [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPEkx.png)

Is there a way to make it work on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of but would be interested to know if you find a solution...

With Hikvision, some of their cameras/firmware seem to work without any browser plugin but their firmware/version control/releases are a nightmare, you would think they would update all their firmware so it all works without a plugin. Even on a windows PC this is a problem, some cameras work without plugin, some work with the plugin and some don't work even WITH the plugin!

I had to use their native software on a Windows PC really to configure everything I needed to.

The only way I have found to view a stream on Ubuntu is to use VLC media player and `Open Network Stream` to view the camera or NVR RTSP stream. Something like:

`rtsp://<ip_of_camera_or_nvr>:554/Streaming/Channels/101`

But that does not help in doing those few config jobs that require the stream to be shown in the web interface (like setting exclusion areas or line crossings etc).

Comment: Confirmed this is working without any configuration with Zorin. you just need to know the username and password